# I think my p2 b broke, can i recover files?

Tags: boot

When I look at the sd card in windows I can see what looks like a boot partition, then there is a larger partition that can been seen by windows but is unreadable. I presume this is a linux partition not fat32? I get a power and act light solid on my board. nothing on screen. doesn't show up on router. [image]

Comment: Yes... the larger partition on your SD card will be `ext4`, whereas the `boot` partition is `fat32`. Your best bet for access to this partition is to make a bootable USB thumb drive (Ubuntu is a good one), and use this bootable drive to boot your Windows machine into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the Pi supports many filesystem types, the most common is called 'ext4'.

Windows does not natively know how to attach an 'ext4' filesystem, but there are a number of free utilities for Windows that do this.

You might try one of these:

- [Ext2read](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)
- [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com)
- [DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)

And I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: used an app called ex2explorer thank you.